# What versioning scheme does Next.js adhere to?

Tags: next.js

This has been surprisingly hard to figure out. I have tried searching around on Google, and looking in their GitHub repo, but haven't found any comments on their versioning scheme. Does anybody know, and can provide a link to their official documentation about it?

Answer (score 1):

They use semantic versioning. I asked on the Next.js GitHub:

> Hi, the Next.js documentation is always pointing to the latest version of next. It is following semantic versioning, so you should not experience breaking changes between patch and minor releases. If you do, it's considered a bug, and you can report them as such and we will look into it.
>
> Certain features can be added in minor releases, those are usually indicated at the top of the page so you know when they became available.
>
> Ref: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/9bb9f07e82357eeb4a15f9c1f5ecb21d600dd433/contributing/repository/release-channels-publishing.md

Source: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/55097#issuecomment-1709787954